# Why grammar does not highlight keyword (Visual Studio Language Server)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-extensions, language-server-protocol

I want to write `Kamailio` Language Server for Visual Studio 2022, I Create a project in [GitHub](https://github.com/soroshsabz/visualstudio-kamailio) with below structure

[image]

And I use `kamailio.tmLanguage.json` from https://github.com/miconda/vscode-kamailio-syntax/blob/master/syntaxes/kamailio.tmLanguage.json that I sure works for Visual Studio Code, So this grammar is correct

But I do not know why my code is not working correctly and does not highlight keyword?

My test with `.kcfg` file extension like below

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.Client;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Kamailio.VisualStudio
{
#pragma warning disable 649
    public class KamailioContentDefinition
    {
        [Export]
        [Name("kamailio")]
        [BaseDefinition(CodeRemoteContentDefinition.CodeRemoteContentTypeName)]
        internal static ContentTypeDefinition KamailioContentTypeDefinition;

        [Export]
        [FileExtension(".kcfg")]
        [ContentType("kamailio")]
        internal static FileExtensionToContentTypeDefinition KamailioFileExtensionDefinition;
    }
#pragma warning restore 649
}
```

Any body can find my mistake?

All code to reproduce my problem is in [GitHub](https://github.com/soroshsabz/visualstudio-kamailio)

Comment: Where is a file with suffix ".kcfg"? There's nothing in your github source code.

Comment: Just a guess, but I suspect that the newer json format is not supported for VS2022 (VSIDE). VSIDE is always years behind VSCode, at least that is what I had to deal with for VS2019. Clone https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples then open the TextmateSample project and run it. It works fine, but that sample uses the old xml syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good news:

It seems that all you need to do is add fileTypes to your kamailio.tmLanguage.json file, e.g.

```json
    "fileTypes": [
        ".cfg"
    ],
```

VS matches TextMate grammars to files based on these properties.

The bad news:

VS is apparently not smart enough to support other ways to filter when you are or aren't applicable.  Specifically, it does not seem to support the `firstLineMatch` property, so it will apply your grammar to all *.cfg files.  If there is another way to filter which files are or are not applicable, I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have this problem and another that explain https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/TextmateGrammar thanks to @kaby76

Comment: I add feature request on developer community to add `firstLineMatch` into visual studio, please vote up this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Support-firstLineMatch-in-tmlanguage-for/10281813